# Export to excel using backgroundworker

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, export-to-excel, closedxml

How to Implement backgroundworker or thread in ASP.Net(C#) WEB Application for Exporting Large amount of Data in to Excel? Is there any another approach to export to excel in background?

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/export_module.master"
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="GenerateReport.aspx.cs"
Inherits="" Async="true" %>


public readonly BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork);
        //worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(WorkerProgressChanged);
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(WorkerCompleted);
    }
}
```

//Export To Excel Click event

```
  protected void btn_Export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {        
    if (!worker.IsBusy){
      worker.RunWorkerAsync("ExportReport");
    }
  }
```

//BackgroundMethod

```
  private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
  {
    exportToExcel();
  }

  private void WorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
  { 
  }
```

//Export To Excel Using ClosedXML

```
  public void ExportReportWithHeaderClosedXML(string reportName, string fileName,  DataTable dataTable)
{
    int usedCells = dataTable.Columns.Count;
    string ReportDate = string.Empty;
    string attachment = "inline;filename=" + fileName + ".xlsx";
    using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
    {

        //Add method of ClosedXML class library only accepts worksheet name of 31 characters.

        IXLWorksheet worksheet = wb.Worksheet(1);           

        //Insert Report Data
        worksheet.Cell(4, 1).InsertTable(dataTable);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();

        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;

        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + fileName + ".xlsx");
        using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
            MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by large amount of data ?

Comment: its more than 40,000 rows which will take time for rendering excel file and makes browser unresponsive so i am trying to generate report in background so that it will not stop user to work on other task

Comment: 40K data is not a large amount of data. It depends on how you write the code and all other dependencies in your application

Comment: There is complex pivoting on data so excel takes time to render data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to start new single thread then it will be usefull.

```
var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += (o, ea) =>
{
       //It will execute after start new Thread.
       //Write your code for execute Export Excel.
};
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, ea) =>
{
       //You will get pointer when this worker finished the job.
};
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: I have tried same way but when user click on export to excel button it shows exception of "Asynchronous operations are not allowed in this context. Page starting an asynchronous operation has to have the Async attribute set to true and an asynchronous operation can only be started on a page prior to PreRenderComplete event." so i have make page Async="true" but still excel file is not generating

Comment: As per my view ScriptManger may need to add at form with runat="server".

Comment: Could you please sent the block of code of export excel for debug and more explanation.

Comment: for export to excel i am using closedXML library

Comment: I have created Sample project It works fine. you can refer it from below link                  "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wt5loCItVV8VcWky5loiC5ZUWjpdQs7-"

Comment: Ok let me know if any issue to implement in your source.

Comment: I have implemented your code in my logic but it fails as i have used "HttpContext.Current.Response" for exporting excel kindly check above my code for export to excel

Comment: Are you facing error in "ExportReportWithHeaderClosedXML()" Method? and closedXML Library is necessary to use for export as per your requirment?

Comment: if i am not using closedXML() and export data using string builder than data might be truncated as there is large amount of data in data table

Comment: I have updated my sample project it is working fine as per your requirement. you can download it from here "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Bt1FXrpR4UfZbwzReBmEALysxFHOPEU6". Let me know If any more issue.

Comment: You can Mark answer to "accepted" and Vote if it is help full to you.

Comment: I have implemented as you have mentioned and it is exporting data to excel properly  but it is not running in background of application how can i make it to run in background of application so that other activity will work as it is

Comment: you can use "BackgroundWorker()" to acomplish this task...Please refer the attched link for more explanation "https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/backgroundworker-in-C-Sharp/". if any issue then comment back.